# Object does not contain the attributes given

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I am trying to use the attributes of a (see code below) I get an error saying the object has no attribute, for example name. hasattr('a','name') outputs false. I want to be able to use the attribute name for instance, in the method display_info but it appears my object does not have any of the attributes given. At the same time the method find_by_attribute works fine and outputs the object with a given attribut, I'm confused here. Perhaps I'm creating my object in a wrong way?

When trying use the say_hi method the same error appears.

```
@dataclass
class Animal:

    name: str 
    species: str
    gender: str
    age: int
    mood: str

    @classmethod
    def say_hi(self):
        print(f'{self.name} the {self.species} says hi!')

    def display_info(self):
        print('Name:',self.name)
        print('Species:',self.species)
        print('Gender:',self.gender)
        print('Age: %d' % self.age)
        print('Mood:',self.mood)

class Zoo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.animals = []

    def add_animal(self):
        print('Adding a new animal to the zoo:')
        name = input('What is it\'s name? ')
        species = input('What species is it? ')
        gender = input('What gender is it? ')
        age = int(input('What age is it? '))
        mood = input('How is the animal feeling? ')
        a = Animal(name, species, gender, age, mood)
        self.animals.append(a)

    def find_by_attribute(self, attribute_name, value):
        return [a for a in self.animals if getattr(a, attribute_name) == value]

a = Zoo()
a.add_animal()
```

Comment: `hasattr('a','name')` and `hasattr(a,'name')` are not the same. Looks like a typo to me.

Comment: Returns false either way :(

Comment: @Hoog, because it's a [data class](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html?highlight=dataclass#module-dataclasses)

Comment: what `a` are you passing here: the `Zoo` or the `Animal`?

Comment: So should I avoid using data class altogether?

Comment: `say_hi` should not be a class method; get rid of the decorator.

Comment: @erkoo, on the contrary: they're quite useful in many cases. And `hasattr` should work fine. Create a separate script with just the `Animal` class and `print(hasattr(Animal(...), 'name'))`.

Comment: @ForceBru Okay, because I suspect the issue might be the way I'm creating the object, since I want the animals to be created through user input via the Zoo class. Should I create a in a different way perhaps?

Comment: @erkoo, if you do `a = Animal(name, species, gender, age, mood)` and then _straight away_ `print(hasattr(a, 'name'))`, does it error out?

Comment: @ForceBru Yes, "NameError: name 'name' is not defined" immediately.

Comment: @erkoo, that's because you didn't surround `name` with quotes, as it's shown in my comment. EDIT: I mean, input actual data to the constructor `Animal` first, like: `a = Animal('Bob', 'dog', 'ummm', 10, 'happy')`

Comment: @ForceBru But I did? Here is the complete error: File "animalclass.py", line 54, in <module>
    a = Animal(name, species, gender, age, mood)
NameError: name 'name' is not defined

Oh, you're right now it returns true

Comment: Yeah, sure, that's because `name` doesn't exist yet. I meant the `a = Animal(...)` line in your code. Put `print(hasattr(a, 'name'))` _right after it_.

Comment: So how would I go about referencing the attributes in the future when they're created from the add_animal method?

Comment: Just like anywhere else? Keep in mind that the `a` of type `Zoo` _does not_ have these attributes, but the `Animal`s in `Zoo().animals` do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, `a` on the last line is different from `a` inside `add_animal` method:

- the first one is an instance of `Zoo` which does not have any attribute called `name`, but it has a list of animals where each has the attributes assigned..
- the second `a` is what made you probably confused, this is a local variable inside the method, added to the `animals` list of the instance of `Zoo`.

so if you want to access the name attribute you need to called it on the elements of the `animals` list inside the instance `a` like this:

```py
a = Zoo()
a.add_animal()                       # answer the inputs ...
print(hasattr(a.animals[0], 'name')  # => True
```

I would suggest not to use the same variable name outside and inside classes/methods, to remove any confusion.

hope this helps

*Edit (answering question in comment: how would I for instance modify display_info to return the animals attributes for a given animal?)*

you don't need the method `display_info`, as `Animal` is a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) you can just print it:

```py
# continuation for code from before

for animal in a.animals:
    print(animal)
```

output something like:

```sh
Animal(name='tiger', species='cat', gender='male', age=12, mood='hungry')
```

if you want to store the info in a string for later use you can:

```py
animal_info = str(a.animals[0])
```

if you want to print a specific animal, say only which has the age 12, you can:

```py
print([animal for animal in a.animals if animal.age == 12])
```

this will show a list of animals, as wanted.

Comment: Okay, thank you that helps. So how would I for instance modify `display_info` to return the animals attributes for a given animal? I feel like using dataclasses just made this a lot harder for me..